# SQL Server 2012: Categorizing NULL values as missing and pending based on occurence

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a data related to student week wise attendance in a study center. It will have Centerid, studentid, week1, week2 and so on.

This is the [Pivoted Schema link](http://rextester.com/PTWT2984) for my data and this is the [link](http://rextester.com/YHFM77163) for my original data.

The student may have missed few weeks in between or few weeks yet to come in future.

What I need is to categorize the missing dates into Missed weeks and Futuree Weeks.

[image: Screenshot sample]

If you check the above screenshot, the NULL values highlighted in red are the missing ones and the NULL values in green are the future ones. When The student attends the class, we will have the date when he attended the class for each week. Hence when he misses the class, there wont be date and will be null. similarly when the week is of future, it will be null as he is yet to attend the class.

I want to classify the red ones as missing and the green ones as future. I was able to do this using a case comparison like

```
WHEN WEEK1 IS NULL AND (WEEK2 is NOT NULL OR WEEK3 is NOT NULL OR WEEK 4 is NOT NULL OR WEEK 5 is NOT NULL OR WEEK6is NOT NULL OR WEEK7 is NOT NULL THEN 'WEEK1_Missing'
WHEN WEEK7 IS NULL AND (WEEK2 is NOT NULL OR WEEK3 is NOT NULL OR WEEK 4 is NOT NULL OR WEEK 5 is NOT NULL OR WEEK6is NOT NULL OR WEEK1 is NOT NULL THEN 'WEEK7_Future'
```

Is there any better approach to this? Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this screenshot the actual table, or is it derived from something else?  Off the top of my head, adding columns for each subsequent week seems like a bad idea, making it hard to write queries.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by this?" categorize the missing dates into Missed weeks and Futuree Weeks"

Comment: Your are the one only knows why it become red  and why it become green..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its basically a derived table. The actual table will hold the week 1, Week 2 in the rows and I have pivoted it to columns using cross apply so that I can write my case statement easily for comparing each week.

Comment: @reds Basically I want to show an aggregated view for each site denoting how many students have missed the classes and how many still have future classes. When The student attends the class, we will have the date when he attended the class for each week. Hence when he misses the class, there wont be date and will be null. similarly when the week is of future, it will be null as he is yet to attend the class.

Comment: @artm, the expected output will be showing an aggregate count of students who have missed the classes based on centerid.

Comment: You need to show us the original data.  A derived table is going to be of little help.

Comment: Show the original data and expected output as text, not image or link or description.

Comment: The date is diff for each employees in a single Week, so  if the Week7 is missing, how can we know that it is Green(Future) or red?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have added the link for my original data and here is the link for the same http://rextester.com/YHFM77163

Comment: The data i have put has past date's and will not be showing the present date.  The logic has to be if there is a null in between it will be shown as missing and if its towards the end then future.

Comment: what happens when a student really missed/absent only last week class? (it always shown green?)

Comment: @AbdulRasheed, The metrics is just to show the number of missed and yet to complete classes for each centers.

Comment: As i've said above, he is the one only knows when it become green and when it become red?

Comment: @reds When The student attends the class, we will have the date when he attended the class for each week. Hence when he misses the class, there wont be date and will be null. similarly when the week is of future, it will be null as he is yet to attend the class. I have just color coded to show the difference between the missing as red and future as green to highlight the difference in what i am looking at. In the real data it will be just null.

Comment: You need to apply your logic in the original data (weeks as rows), _then_ pivot it for display purposes. Don't try and apply logic on the pivotted data. What are you actually displaying this in?

Comment: I just looked at your data again. How do you know WEEK5 is in the pastor in the future? in your example, this week has both green and red cells. From your explanation so far it seems you're missing info. Why is 1005 red and 1006 green in WEEK5? That information doens't exist

Comment: The missing or future is determined based on the empty values and the next non empty value. For instance if i take studentid 1-3004, the student has attended week 1, not attended week 2, attended the rest of the weeks till week 7. Hence Week 2 is considered as missing.

Comment: So basically if there is an entry _after_ a missing entry, it's missing. Sorry if you already exaplained that

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below will calculate some kind of binary string from the weeks.

The binary string is used to determine if the records have future and/or missing weeks.

Which is then used to get the totals.

```
select [CENTERID], 
sum(case when calc like '0%' then 1 else 0 end) as future,
sum(case when calc like '%10%' then 1 else 0 end) as missing
from (
    SELECT [CENTERID], [STUDENTID],
    case when WEEK7 is null then '0' else '1' end +
    case when WEEK6 is null then '0' else '1' end +
    case when WEEK5 is null then '0' else '1' end +
    case when WEEK4 is null then '0' else '1' end +
    iif(WEEK3 is null,'0','1') + -- iif as alternative if you want to golf code this
    iif(WEEK2 is null,'0','1') +
    iif(WEEK1 is null,'0','1') as calc
    FROM week_data
) q
group by [CENTERID];
```

Returns:

```
CENTERID future missing 
1001     0      2 
1002     1      1 
1003     1      2 
1004     1      1 
1005     0      2 
1006     1      0 
1007     3      3
```

To apply such trick directly on the original data:

```
select [CENTERID], 
sum(case when calc like '0%' then 1 else 0 end) as future,
sum(case when calc like '%10%' then 1 else 0 end) as missing
from (
    SELECT [CENTERID], [STUDENTID], 
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 7' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) +
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 6' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) +
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 5' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) +
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 4' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) +
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 3' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) +
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 2' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) +
    max(case when [WEEKNAME] = 'week 1' and [WEEKDATE] is not null then '1' else '0' end) as calc
    FROM original_data
    GROUP BY [CENTERID], [STUDENTID]
    ) q
group by [CENTERID];
```

If you just want to replace the nulls by something like 'Missing' or 'Future', then realise that you can use a CASE WHEN within a CASE WHEN.
For example:

```
SELECT [CENTERID], [STUDENTID]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK1 IS NULL 
  THEN (CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(WEEK2, WEEK3, WEEK4, WEEK5, WEEK6, WEEK7) IS NULL 
        THEN 'Future'
        ELSE 'Missing'
        END)
  ELSE WEEK1 
  END) as [WEEK1]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK2 IS NULL
  THEN (CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(WEEK3, WEEK4, WEEK5, WEEK6, WEEK7) IS NULL 
        THEN 'Future'
        ELSE 'Missing'
        END)
  ELSE WEEK2 END) as [WEEK2]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK3 IS NULL
  THEN (CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(WEEK4, WEEK5, WEEK6, WEEK7) IS NULL 
        THEN 'Future'
        ELSE 'Missing'
        END)
  ELSE WEEK3 
  END) as [WEEK3]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK4 IS NULL
  THEN (CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(WEEK5, WEEK6, WEEK7) IS NULL 
        THEN 'Future'
        ELSE 'Missing'
        END)
  ELSE WEEK4 
  END) as [WEEK4]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK5 IS NULL
  THEN (CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(WEEK6, WEEK7) IS NULL 
        THEN 'Future'
        ELSE 'Missing'
        END)
  ELSE WEEK5 
  END) as [WEEK5]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK6 IS NULL
  THEN (CASE 
        WHEN WEEK7 IS NULL 
        THEN 'Future'
        ELSE 'Missing'
        END)
  ELSE WEEK6 
  END) as [WEEK6]
,(CASE 
  WHEN WEEK7 IS NULL 
  THEN 'Future'
  ELSE WEEK7 
  END) as [WEEK7]
FROM week_data
```

Comment: I strongly suggested applying the logic _before_ the pivot, not after

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks for your reply. I will check out your code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Indeed, running it directly on the original data could give better performance. Such query has been added.

Comment: Not only that - you don't need a case statement per column